# is there a way to connect mongodb with phoenix framework 1.4 version

Tags: mongodb, phoenix-framework, ecto

i am trying to use mongodb in my phoenix application. however the official documentation refers to only RDBMS (postgresql). is there a way to connect to mongodb with phoenix framework 1.4.

i am trying to build an application in phoenix which will have unstructured data. i see from the documentation of ECTO mongodb for old version. for 1.4 version of the phoenix, there is no option specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a MongoDB/Ecto integration that is up to date with Ecto 3 yet.

But Phoenix is not your application, it is an interface. It provides the web interface. You can have other things in your application apart from Phoenix, and you can wrap MongoDB in a way that your Phoenix-based-interface can consume the data.

So the answer to your question is yes there is a way to connect MongoDB with Phoenix 1.4 but it is not plug-and-play.

Edit: I threw (emphasis on threw) together an example which can be found [here](https://github.com/JustAnotherSoul/AlchemicalMongo)

[image: Some data in mongo]
[image: Data in the Phoenix App]
[image]

Basically it involves two applications: one a stock elixir application that is just mongodb 0.4.7 and wraps some functions. The other is a phoenix app that uses the aforementioned mongodb wrapper app. The Phoenix App needs to be created with `mix phx.new --no-ecto`, ostensibly you could do this as one app, but this gives you a bit more leeway.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please post a solution as to how can we talk to mongo from Phoenix. I tried to look at different sources. However could not find any. Any assistance in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you please share any example (if you implemented) demonstrating the way to connect mongodb from Phoenix. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'll see if I can get something small working here after work.

Comment: @pindiprolichaitanya It is done. There is a small working example linked above.

Comment: thank you very much for sharing the code and helping in understanding. it is very much helpful. Your project gave me better understanding of how can i configure database connection in a separate project and then bind it to the main project. thanks for your time and support.

Comment: No problem. If you click the check to accept the answer that would help others who have similar questions to see the solution more quickly in the future. Good luck!

Comment: Did accepted it. Thanks for your response and time.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MongoDB in Phoenix is very simple. You don't need to use the Ecto stuff, because it is designed for relational database like PostgreSQL. You talk directly to the mongodb driver:

You can put the connection url into the config environment (config.ex, for example) of your Phoenix app:

```
config :app, :mongodb,
   url: "mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019/my_database?replicaSet=my_replica_set"
```

The URL specifies a replica set of three nodes.

In `application.ex` you add a worker like this:

old style:

```
worker(Mongo, [[name: :mongo, url: Application.get_env(:app, :mongodb)[:url], timeout: 60_000, pool_size: 10]])
```

need style:

```
{Mongo, [name: :mongo, url: Application.get_env(:app, :mongodb)[:url], timeout: 60_000, pool_size: 10]}
```

The worker starts the GenServer with a timeout of 60 seconds and a pool size of 10 connection. After that you can use the MongoDB as usually:

```
Mongo.find(:mongo, "accounts", %{"email" => the_email})
```